# how to execute this basic parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

how to execute this one in plsql..

```
create or replace procedure p11(a in number, b out number)
is
begin
b:=a*a;
dbms_output.put_line(b);
end;

variable a number;
variable b number;
```

what statement I have to give to execute; Trying to learn

Comment: execute p11(10,b) gives b not declared ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables you define with the keyword `variable` can be used as bind variables, not like PL/SQL variables, so you need to add a colon (`:`).

```
SQL> variable b number;

SQL> create or replace procedure p11(a in number, b out number)
is
begin
b:=a*a;
dbms_output.put_line(b);
end;
 /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p11(10, :b);                 <----- ':' in front of b

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :b

         B
----------
       100
```

The line `variable a number;` has no effect on your program, `a` is a local variable to `p11` from its argument list.